# Coding not pulling in column names

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I got a lot of the coding on this site and have been working on it. I am able to import my database but I cannot get the column names to show up on the window.

It only shows the two buttons **Add item** and **cancel**

The following coding is my venture into Python programming.

> // This program will build a sqlite database by importing a csv file.
>   Eventually I will be able to search for data.

```
import csv
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

# Create the database
connection = sqlite3.connect('attendance5.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Create the table
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS student')
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE student(StuID TEXT, LastName TEXT, FirstName    TEXT, Grade TEXT)')
connection.commit()

# Load the CSV file into CSV reader
csvfile = open('attendance1.csv', 'r')
creader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

# Iterate through the CSV reader, inserting values into the database
for t in creader:
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO student VALUES (?,?,?,?)', t)

# Close the csv file, commit changes, and close the connection

csvfile.close()
connection.commit()
connection.close()

def main():
  db = 'attendance.db'
  tbl = 'student'
 # root = tk.Tk()
columns = 'StudID TEXT', 'LastName TEXT', 'FirstName TEXT', 'Grade TEXT'
root = tk.Tk()
demo_window = EntryWindow(root,*[db, tbl])
root.mainloop()


class EntryWindow(tk.Frame):

"""
Provides a simple data entry window for a given table in given database.
Automatically generates labels and entry fields based on the column
headers for the given table.  Provides a button to submit the row of data
into the table and a button to close window.
"""
def __init__(self, master=None, *args):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master = master
    self.database = args[0]
    self.table = args[1]
    self.init_window()

def init_window(self):
    """Build the entry window."""

    self.master.title('Enter data into {}'.format(self.table.upper()))
    self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S), padx=10, pady=5)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def get_col_names(self):
        """Retrieve column names for given table in database."""

        with sqlite3.connect(self.database) as conn:
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute("PRAGMA table_info('{}')".format(self.table))
            # Currently only uses one value from returned tuple.
            # TODO: Add logic to utilize type, not null and PK fields.
            self.col_names = [x[1] for x in c.fetchall()]
        return self.col_names

    self.column_names = get_col_names(self)

    # Add a label and entry box for each column in table.
    # TODO: Add functionality to gray out primary key fields where the
    #       database should be assigning the next value.
    # TODO: Add some validation logic.
    self.item_entry = []
    for item in self.column_names:
        num = len(self.item_entry)
        print(num, ' --> '+item)
        tk.Label(self, text=item).grid(row=num, column=0,
                                       pady=1, sticky=E)
        self.item_entry.append(tk.Entry(self))
        self.item_entry[num].grid(row=num, column=1, pady=1, padx=5)

    def add_item(self):
        """Get entries from input fields and insert into database table."""
        entries = [e.get() for e in self.item_entry]
         #Build the SQL statement
        stmnt = ('insert into {0}({1}) values ({2})'
                 .format(self.table, ','.join(self.column_names),
                         ':'+',:'.join(self.column_names)))
        print(stmnt, entries)
        with sqlite3.connect(self.database) as conn:
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute(stmnt, entries)
            conn.commit()
        clear_fields(self)

  #  def clear_fields(self):
   #    """Clear fields of entry window and return focus to first field."""
   # for e in self.item_entry:
   #       e.delete(0, END)
  #  self.item_entry[0].focus()

     #Add button to submit user inputs into database.
    submit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Add Item', width=8,
                              command=lambda: add_item(self))
    submit_button.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=E, pady=10, padx=1)

    # Add a cancel button which closes window.
    quit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Cancel', width=8,
                            command=self.quit)
    quit_button.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10, padx=1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this? Have you done some basic debugging such as validating what you're getting back from the database, validating that the code that creates the headings is running, etc.?

Comment: Yes I have commented out sections to see what kind of errors I received and worked from there. It does create the database and there is data in there. But cannot get the column names to show. I am very new at this.

Comment: Your indents around get_col_names are screwy.  Are you sure that get_col_names actually gets called, and that self.column_names contains something when the labels are created.